# Excute python script on Raspberry PI from Apache Laravel PHP controller

Tags: php, python, linux, laravel, raspberry-pi

I have a python script on a raspberry in /home/pi/Test.py which could be called from a laravel php controller.

On the Raspberry there is Raspian installed, Apache, PHP 7.3, Python

I tried it via cmdline

python Test.py 4444 > works

via local php server

```
php artisan serve
```

/localhost:8000/setValue/666 > works, returnvalue 0

Then i deployed the application to the Apache2 directory

```
/var/www/html/Project
```

There i called the Service again

```
localhost:80/Project/setValues/666 > nothing, returnvalue 1
```

here is my code

```
chdir('/home/pi');
$cmd('python Test.py ' . $param);
exec($cmd,$out,$status);
return $status
```

Executing this from the php debug server this returns "0", from apache "1"

i tried

```
exec ()
shell_exec()
passthrough()
```

Everything the same - works from the local server, not from apache.

I changed the owner to www-data and changed the rights to 775 in both the python script and laravel project, i also added the www-data as sudoer but nothing worked.

I think is has to do something with executable rights but what else to do?

EDIT:
I found a note in the Apache error.log

GPIO.setup (DATA, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeError: not running on a RPi!

it seems that www-data can not access the GPIO settings, the user "pi" although can which means - how to i enable www-data to have the same rights of the user "pi"?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after struggling for hours:

first of all add www-data to gpio group

```
>sudo adduser www-data gpio > not working
```

and then i upgraded the firmware with

```
> sudo rpi-update
```

Finally it worked from the Apache Server. Thanks to this Posting
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root and this User https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/13650/joan it worked. Thanks a lot!